# ATAPI interactive MediaModes and c#

Tags: c#, .net, phone-call, tapi

I had been trying to establish a call using ATAPI and c# . 
although when I am opening a line using my modem 
Conexant USB CX93010 ACF and check for the supported MediaMode i got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHGuJ.png)

but when I am trying to open a line using interactive mediaMode i receive an exception 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPTsD.png)

and this is the message:
{"lineOpen failed [0xFFFFFFFF8000002F] Invalid media mode\r\n"}
and the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using JulMar.Atapi;
namespace SimpleCall
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TapiManager z = new TapiManager("SimpleCall");
        z.Initialize();
        TapiLine[] phone = z.Lines;

        TapiLine line = phone[16];
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        line.Open(MediaModes.InteractiveVoice);
        Console.WriteLine(line.Capabilities.MediaModes);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question. This line doesn't support this media mode. As you can see. Use a tapi browser or TB20 or another tool to check the supported medias.

Answer (score 0):

Open line in Modem media mode should work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using JulMar.Atapi;
namespace SimpleCall
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

{
    TapiManager z = new TapiManager("SimpleCall");
    z.Initialize();
    TapiLine[] phone = z.Lines;

    TapiLine line = phone[16];
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    line.Open(MediaModes.Modem);
    Console.WriteLine(line.Capabilities.MediaModes);
}
}
}
```